# Дайте реальный пример где алгоритм O(N*N) быстрее чем O(N) для некоторого N>10 ?

Tags: алгоритм, сложность, c++

Случайно наткнулся на эту задачу в книге Страуструпа по С++
("Язык программирования С++ спец. изд /Пер. с англ, - М.; СПб.: "Издательство БИНОМ" - "Невский диалект", 2002г. - 1099с., ил.) Глава 18. Алгоритмы и объекты функции. 611 стр. первое упражнение.

Ясно что O большое обозначает асимптотическую сложность и это просто значит что O(N*N)растет не быстрее чем N*N, то есть теоретически такая ситуация возможна. Тем не менее сходу я не смог придумать/найти пару таких алгоритмов. В самом тексте главы тоже ничего не сказано про это. У кого-нибудь есть идеи?

Comment: а это должен быть  один алгоритм, или может быть два разных?

Comment: Понятия не имею, наверное два разных алгоритма решающих одну и ту же задачу. Текст указан дословно в заголовке. Больше там ничего не сказано.

Comment: могу привести пример, когда алгоритм с квадратичной сложностью быстрее, чем алгоритм с логарифмической сложностью.

Comment: Это было бы весьма кстати

Comment: - Возьмите любой алгоритм, у которого константа в `O(N)` равна `231452356246373458458` и алгоритм `O(N^2)` с константой 1. Почти наверняка найдется такое `N,` для которого второй алгоритм будет быстрее по всем входным словам длины `N`.

- С практической точки зрения, насколько я помню, это верно, если, например, сравнивать `bubble sort` и `bucket/radix sort`.

Comment: пример, когда алгоритм с квадратной сложностью быстрее - это сортировка практически отсортированных массивов. Сравниваем простую сортировку пузырьком и quick sort. Конечно, пример надуманный, но...

Comment: В этой ситуации говорить о *быстрее* можно только о *реализации*, но не о самом алгоритме. Для алгоритма как такового сравниваются только функции роста, а конкретные времена — только для реализаций. А тут вам и флаг в руки — напишите плохую реализацию O(N) и хорошую O(N^2) :)